# Task When.All invoke just first Task

Tags: c#, task

I have two tasks that invoked async.

```
await Task.WhenAll (
    ServerCommandWrapper (DoSomething1),
    ServerCommandWrapper (DoSomething2)
);
```

Server Command Wrapper invoke my delegate and await it.

```
protected virtual async Task ServerCommandWrapper(Func<Task> action)
{
    if (IsBusy) {               
       return;
    }
    try {
        IsBusy = true;
        await action();
    } catch (System.Exception ex) {
        ReportError (ex);
    } finally {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

And my methods are:

```
protected virtual async Task DoSomething1 ()
{
    await Connect();
}

protected virtual async Task DoSomething2()
{           
    Data = await GetSomethingAsync();
}
```

When I try to start two methods async It just start first one in array. What Im doing wrong?

Comment: That would suggest that the implementation of `Connect` is blocking. What does `Connect` do?

Comment: WhenAll doesn't invoke tasks. It *awaits* tasks  that have already started. That global `IsBusy` variable though, guarantees only one call to `ServerCommandWrapper ` will execute its action. All others will see `IsBusy` raised and return. *Why* are you using this "wrapper" if you want to execute multiple tasks in parallel? Or are you trying to do something different?

Comment: Are you trying to execute one asynchronous method after the other? Just do `await DoSomething1();await DoSomething2();` then.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Try to start taks parallel. Oh I understand know , the problem is from IsBusy. When other method start task the IsBusy is true. Thanks a lot. Can you answer the question that I marked it correct. Maybe someone get this "kid's" problem. I'm using wrapper to don't write each time try catch block.

Comment: @spender It just connect to signalR. It doest block anything.